# defining a javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, object, entities

How can express this javascript object defintion in a way that value of first  InvoiceNo does not get replaced with second value?

> EDIT< Ultimately i want an object called myObject that contains an array of Invoice numbers. Each invoice number would have a related bill and ship number...

```
var myObject = {};

myObject = { "InvoiceNo" : 44444, 
             "Shipping":
                {
                    "ShipTo": 22345 , "BillTo": 43456 
                }
            }

// some more code here that would capture user input or a data from a remote data feed...

myObject = { "InvoiceNo" : 555555, 
             "Shipping":
                {
                    "ShipTo": 32345 , "BillTo": 33456 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? From what I see, you could just assign your second invoice to a different variable, say `myOtherObject`.

Comment: Are you looking for an array?  That might be what you are talking about:  `var objects=new Array();`  Then `objects.push(myObject);`  Dunno though...

Comment: You can make an array of objects - holding separate instances.

Comment: Bakudan - or an object that contains an array of invoices?

Comment: `'use strict'`, but that may not be what you want either :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make something simple like this:

```
var myObject = [
    {
        "InvoiceNo": 44444,
        "Shipping": { "ShipTo": 22345, "BillTo": 43456 }
    },
    {
        "InvoiceNo": 555555,
        "Shipping": { "ShipTo": 32345, "BillTo": 33456 }
    }
];
console.log(myObject[0].InvoiceNo); // 0 - the first object inside the array
console.log(myObject[0].Shipping.ShipTo); // access the "ShipTo" property of the first element
```

For something more complicated [JSON <sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate.

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EELBk/)

Answer (score 1):

Far as I can tell, you're looking for this...

```
var myObject = { 
    "44444": {"ShipTo": 22345 , "BillTo": 43456 },
    "555555":{"ShipTo": 32345 , "BillTo": 33456 }
};

myObject[ "777777" ] = {"ShipTo": 88888 , "BillTo": 99999 }
```

Or this...

```
var myObject = { 
    "invoices": [
         {"invoice":"44444", "ShipTo": 22345 , "BillTo": 43456 },
         {"invoice":"555555", "ShipTo": 32345 , "BillTo": 33456 }
    ]
};

myObject.invoices.push( {"invoice":"777777", "ShipTo": 88888 , "BillTo": 99999 } )
```

Comment: Yes, that's the right direction! but if I divide that into 2 or more statements, each new statement clobbers the previous one.

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge: So you need to know how to add an item to an object?

Comment: sort of.  I think I need a object that contains an array of Invoice Numbers each with object properties.  Maybe i should be using an array here?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"an array of Invoice Numbers each with object properties"*.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define any invoices at the time `myObject` is initialized. You can dynamically add them later:

```
var myObject = { 
    invoices: []
}

myObject.invoices.push({"invoice":"44444", "ShipTo": 22345 , "BillTo": 43456 });
myObject.invoices.push({"invoice":"555555", "ShipTo": 32345 , "BillTo": 33456 });
```

Comment: that's even better. You are defining an object with an array up front, then populating when the data exists. nice!